# backward-paragraph skips closest paragraph

Tags: emacs

I've modified the variable paragraph-start to count lines starting with .*: as a paragraph start:

```
(setq paragraph-start "\f\\|[ \t]*$\\|[ \t]*[0-9.]\.\\|.*:$\\|" )
```

However, if I have a buffer:

```
foo: 
bar:
baz: some stuff
more
_
```

(Where _ indicates point location)
Then the first backward-paragraph skips to the beginning of the line 'bar:', not the line starting with 'baz:' as expected.  How do I change this behaviour/why is it behaving this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have `$` after `:`:

```
"\f\\|[ \t]*$\\|[ \t]*[0-9.]\.\\|.*:$\\|"
```

`$` matches at the end of a line. So the part of your regexp that matches something followed by `:` also requires that nothing follow the `:`.

The first line (going backward from point) that ends in a `:` is the `bar:` line.

(Note too that you might not want `.*:`, if you want to exclude the possibility that what precedes the `:` not include a `:`, e.g., if you want to exclude `a:b:c foo`. To exclude `:`, use `[^:]*` instead of `.*`.  And to exclude a lone `:`, use `[^:]+`.)